# Neo4j displaying path of a hiearchy, and select the depth of hierarchy to display

Tags: neo4j

My first Neo4j question - so gentle please

Here is some ascii art of what I want to show

1 - I have 2 nodes, Node 1 and Node 5, where Node1 has OUTPUTS relationship to Node3 and Node3 OUTPUTS to node 5

2 - In the case of Node 3, it is decomposed into Nodes 2,3 and 4, where
Node 2 and Node 4 are CHILD of Node 3.

I want to be able to selectively show a path that has the parent node only
**PATH A** below
OR
where I want to include the child nodes as well, **PATH B**

**PATH A**

```
 node1     -[:OUTPUT]->           node3           - [:INPUT]->      node5

                                    |
                     -----[CHILD]---- -------[CHILD]-----
                    |                                    |
                    |                                    |
  node1-[:OUTPUT]->node2-[:INPUT]->node3-[OUTPUT]->node4-[INPUT]-> node5
```

**PATH B**

thanks all

Comment: Do all these relationships actually exist (i.e. `node2` is both a `CHILD` and and `INPUT` of `node3`)? When you say "show", you actually mean "query", right? Could you give examples of what you've tried, so we have more context?

Comment: The subgraph in your diagram cannot be represented as a single "path", since it has more than 2 endpoints. What is it that you are really trying to do?